# Linux top -b show specific columns only

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I would like to capture the output of the top command to use in another program however I only need certain information, more precisely I only need the USER, PID, CPU, COMMAND columns.
I already have the command `top -b -n 1 | sed -n '7,12p'` to filter the top 5 results but I cannot go any further because I do not know much about sed/awk.

Example: here is what I get

```
PID USER    PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
4 root      20   0   98748  50608   4608 S  6.4  4.9 212:12.16 X  
1 root      20   0    2132    128     96 S  0.0  0.0   0:07.62 init  
2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd  
3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   7:28.54 ksoftirqd/0
```

and here is what i want

```
PID USER %CPU COMMAND  
 4 root  6.4 X  
 1 root  0.0 init  
 2 root  0.0 kthreadd  
 3 root  0.0 ksoftirqd/0
```

Comment: The man page explains how to pick columns, look for the -o option.

Comment: @aet it does not in my version, -o is used to sort by fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pass to:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$9,$NF}'
```

Comment: this worked, added some formatting so the final command looks like `top -b -n 1 -o +%CPU | sed -n '7,12p' | awk '{printf "%6s  %-4s  %-4s  %-s\n",$1,$2,$9,$NF}'`

Answer (score 1):

Everything combined.

```
top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>6 && NR<13 {printf "%6s %-4s %-4s %-s\n",$1,$2,$9,$NF}'
```